# Is there a way to partially match a route in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I want to match every route ending with -xyz suffix to the same router.
is there a way I can achieve it in laravel?
example:

- abc.com/abc-xyz
- abc.com/pqr-xyz

Both routes should lead to the same controller function. The urls will be dynamically generated in the blade file, so anything with -xyz need to be redirected to the same controller.

Comment: have you tried this type?
``Route::get('/{part}-xyz', [UserController::class, 'index']);``
Or you want to make group prefix?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `where` method to define regex to match the routes.

```
Route::get('{page}', function ($page) {
  dd($page);
})->where('page', '[A-Z-0-9_a-z]+\-xyz');
```

Tested for the below samples:

```
asdasd-xyz
2523_ewrew65s-ad5sd4ad-xyz
123-xyz
```